# How to fill a region between two curves in Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

So basically I am trying to reproduce a modified version of this figure:

[image]

This is what I have done so far, and I would like to fill the region between u1 and u2 with the same gradient color:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}  
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{2mm}

\begin{document}

\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{110}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\rvec}{.8}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\thetavec}{30}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\phivec}{60}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5,tdplot_main_coords]

\coordinate (O1) at (0,0,0);

\tdplotsetcoord{P}{\rvec}{\thetavec}{\phivec}

\draw[] (O1) -- (1,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x_1$};
\draw[] (O1) -- (0,1,0) node[anchor=north west]{$x_2$};
\draw[] (O1) -- (0,0,1) node[anchor=south]{$x_3$};

\draw[thick,-stealth] (O1) -- (.25,0,0) node[anchor=north west]{$\mathbf{e}_1$};
\draw[thick,-stealth] (O1) -- (0,.25,0) node[anchor=north west]{$\mathbf{e}_2$};
\draw[thick,-stealth] (O1) -- (0,0,.25) node[anchor=north east]{$\mathbf{e}_3$};

\coordinate (O2) at (0,0.5,0.5);

\draw[thick,-stealth,color=black] (O1) -- (O2);

\draw[thick,-stealth] (O2) -- (0,0.85,0.25) node[anchor=south west]{$\mathbf{g}_1$};
\draw[thick,-stealth] (O2) -- (0,.75,0.75) node[anchor=west]{$\mathbf{g}_2$};
\draw[thick,-stealth] (O2) -- (0,0.35,0.75) node[anchor= west,pos=0.9]{$\mathbf{g}_3$};

\draw [draw=black, >=latex, thick] (O2) to [bend left=8] coordinate [pos=7/8] (q2n) (0,0.9,0.1) coordinate (q2) node [right] {$u_1$ curve};
\draw [draw=black, >=latex, thick] (O2) to [bend left=8] coordinate [pos=7/8] (q3n) (0,1,0.8) coordinate (q3) node [right] {$u_2$ curve};
\draw [draw=black, >=latex, thick] (O2) to [bend right=8] coordinate [pos=7/8] (q1n) (0,0.2,0.8) coordinate (q1) node [anchor=south] {$u_3$ curve};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How about something like `\shade [left color=gray!50, right color=white] (O2) to [bend left=8] (q3) to [bend left=8] (q2) to [bend right=8] (O2);` ?

Comment: @mark an answer? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A shading will do it. Here a custom horizontal shading is used to (try to) avoid sharp lines at the edge of the of shaded region. How successful this is may be viewer dependent. Also, the shading is put on a background layer so it doesn't cover the lines:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{110}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\rvec}{.8}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\thetavec}{30}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\phivec}{60}

\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading{fade out}{100bp}{
color(0bp)=(gray);color(60bp)=(white);
color(90bp)=(white);color(100bp)=(white)}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5, tdplot_main_coords, line cap=round]

\coordinate (O1) at (0,0,0);

\tdplotsetcoord{P}{\rvec}{\thetavec}{\phivec}

\draw (O1) -- (1,0,0) node [below left]  {$x_1$};
\draw (O1) -- (0,1,0) node [below right] {$x_2$};
\draw (O1) -- (0,0,1) node [above]       {$x_3$};

\draw [thick, -stealth] (O1) -- (.25,0,0) node [below right] {$\mathbf{e}_1$};
\draw [thick, -stealth] (O1) -- (0,.25,0) node [below right] {$\mathbf{e}_2$};
\draw [thick, -stealth] (O1) -- (0,0,.25) node [below left]  {$\mathbf{e}_3$};

\coordinate (O2) at (0,0.5,0.5);

\draw [thick, -stealth] (O1) -- (O2);

\draw [thick, -stealth] (O2) -- (0,0.85,0.25) 
  node [above right] {$\mathbf{g}_1$};
\draw [thick, -stealth] (O2) -- (0,0.75,0.75) 
  node [right] {$\mathbf{g}_2$};
\draw [thick, -stealth] (O2) -- (0,0.35,0.75) 
  node [right, pos=0.9] {$\mathbf{g}_3$};

\draw [draw=black, >=latex, thick] (O2) to [bend left=8]  
  coordinate [pos=7/8] (q2n) (0,0.9,0.1) 
  coordinate (q2) node [right] {$u_1$ curve};
\draw [draw=black, >=latex, thick] (O2) to [bend left=8]  
  coordinate [pos=7/8] (q3n) (0,1,0.8) 
  coordinate (q3) node [right] {$u_2$ curve};
\draw [draw=black, >=latex, thick] (O2) to [bend right=8] 
  coordinate [pos=7/8] (q1n) (0,0.2,0.8) 
  coordinate (q1) node [anchor=south] {$u_3$ curve};

\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\shade [shading=fade out, shading angle=-15] 
  (O2) to [bend left=8] (q3) to [bend left=8] (q2) to [bend right=8] (O2);
\end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]